# php - get content from second pair of quotes in string

Tags: php, regex, quotes

I'm trying to get the contents of the second quotes and only the second quotes from a string. Right now I'm able to get the contents of all three quotes. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to just print the second value in the output array?

Text

```
2014-06-02 11:48:41.519 -0700   Information 94  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (207.230.229.204) [207.230.229.204]" opening database "FMServer_Sample" as "Admin".
```

PHP

```
if (preg_match_all('~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~', $line, $matches))
                $database_names = $matches[2];

print_r($database);
```

Output

```
[WebDirect] (207.230.229.204) [207.230.229.204], FMServer_Sample, Admin
```

Comment: `$matches[2][1]` will have the desired result

Comment: ...or `$matches[0][1]` to leave the quotes in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it this way:

```
$re = '~(["\'])[^"\']+\1[^"\']*(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~';
$str = '2014-06-02 11:48:41.519 -0700   Information 94  NICOLE  Client "[WebDirect] (207.230.229.204) [207.230.229.204]" opening database "FMServer_Sample" as "Admin".';

if ( preg_match($re, $str, $m) )
   echo $m[3]; // FMServer_Sample
```

Answer (score 0):

The match group starts at [0] and since you're using `preg_match_all` you get [3] groups. The array is the first array of $matches, so it also starts at zero. You could use it like this:

```
if (preg_match_all('~(["\'])([^"\']+)\1~', $line, $matches))
                $database_names = $matches[0][1];

print_r($database_names);
```